# SELECT com CASE roda no phpMyAdmin mas não passando passando em PHP

Tags: mysql

Tenho um problema com um SQL que roda perfeitamente no phpMyAdmin, mas  não  roda passando a consulta para o banco pelo PHP.

Consulta copiada do campo SQL do phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT `idforma_pagamento`, `habilitado`, `descricao`,
CASE forma_pagamento.tipo
WHEN 0 
THEN  'A PRASO'
WHEN 1 
THEN  'A VISTA'
END AS tipo,

CASE forma_pagamento.entrada
WHEN 0 
THEN  'SIM'
WHEN 1 
THEN  'NÃO'
END AS entrada
FROM forma_pagamento
WHERE 1
```

Mesma consulta passada para a variável `$query` no PHP:

```
"SELECT `idforma_pagamento`, `habilitado`, `descricao`,"
            ."CASE forma_pagamento.tipo"
            ."WHEN 0" 
            ."THEN  'A PRASO'"
            ."WHEN 1" 
            ."THEN  'A VISTA'"
            ."END AS tipo,"

            ."CASE forma_pagamento.entrada"
            ."WHEN 0" 
            ."THEN  'SIM'"
            ."WHEN 1" 
            ."THEN  'NÃO'"
            ."END AS entrada"
            ."FROM forma_pagamento"
            ."WHERE 1";
```

Alguém aí pode me ajudar

Comment: Faltam-te espaços dumas linhas para as outras, senão fica tudo colado `CASE forma_pagamento.tipoWHEN 0` assim como está.

Comment: Detalhe PRAZO ao invés de PRASO ;)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que te faltam espaços de umas linhas para as outras, assim como está a `$query` fica:

```
SELECT `idforma_pagamento`, `habilitado`, `descricao`,CASE forma_pagamento.tipoWHEN 0...
```

Adicionando os espaços a cada linha já funciona:

```
"SELECT `idforma_pagamento`, `habilitado`, `descricao`, "
        ."CASE forma_pagamento.tipo "
        ."WHEN 0 " 
        ."THEN  'A PRASO' "
        ."WHEN 1 " 
        ."THEN  'A VISTA' "
        ."END AS tipo, "

        ."CASE forma_pagamento.entrada "
        ."WHEN 0 " 
        ."THEN  'SIM' "
        ."WHEN 1 " 
        ."THEN  'NÃO' "
        ."END AS entrada "
        ."FROM forma_pagamento "
        ."WHERE 1";
```

Comment: Obrigado pessoal. As duas alternativas funcionaram

Comment: @ReinaldoAnício se as duas respostas o ajudaram, escolha a que achar ser a certa e marque a como certa com o visto ao lado da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Faltam os espaços, a concatenação de string esta gerando coisas como `tipoWHEN`. acredito que você poderia usar uma sintaxe menos propensa a erros, por exemplo:

```
<?php   
$query = "
SELECT `idforma_pagamento`,
       `habilitado`,
       `descricao`,
       CASE forma_pagamento.tipo
       WHEN 0 THEN 'A PRASO'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'A VISTA'
       END AS tipo,
       CASE forma_pagamento.entrada
       WHEN 0 THEN 'SIM'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'NÃO'
       END AS entrada
FROM forma_pagamento
WHERE 1";
```

Ou

```
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT `idforma_pagamento`,
       `habilitado`,
       `descricao`,
       CASE forma_pagamento.tipo
       WHEN 0 THEN 'A PRASO'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'A VISTA'
       END AS tipo,
       CASE forma_pagamento.entrada
       WHEN 0 THEN 'SIM'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'NÃO'
       END AS entrada
FROM forma_pagamento
WHERE 1
SQL;
```